# Python 3 Open URL line by line from file or list

Tags: python, printing, get

Need help to figure out how to do browser.get for multiple URLS

Here is the current code

```
#OPEN FILE
import sys
f = open("ids.txt", 'w')
sys.stdout = f

#GRAB IDS
ids = [i.get_attribute('id').replace("name-", "") for i in 
browser.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[@id[starts-with(.,"name")]]')]

#STATIC URL
url = ("https://www.someurlhere.com/page.html?id=")

#PRINT IDS & MAP TO STATIC URL
for id in ids:
    print("https://www.someurlhere.com/page.html?id=",id,sep='')
    #browser.get(url, id) 
    #This gives error get() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

The print produces a file ids.txt which shows all urls line by line with ids
example:

https://www.someurlhere.com/page.html?id=12345678

https://www.someurlhere.com/page.html?id=87654321

https://www.someurlhere.com/page.html?id=87283798

This is the correct urls I want to load

Now, I need help to do a browser.get for each url in list 1 by 1, then grab data from each page loaded.

Usually I would do the following but it doesn't produce the correct urls I'm looking for;

```
links = [i.get_attribute('href') for i in 
browser.find_elements_by_xpath('.//a[contains(., "name")]')]
for url in links:
    print (url, end=',')
    browser.get(url)
    time.sleep(2)

#then do something on each page
```

This works and opens page by page, but produces the wrong urls

I need a way to open each url 1 by 1

Any help appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Did you copy and paste this? Cause your indentation (e.g. in the `for` loop) is off.

Comment: No, everything up to print works fine. Just when I try browser.get i cannot get it to work as expected. To load 1 url after the other in the results

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to figure out a way to solve this myself

I changed the initial id variable as follows;

```
ids = [i.get_attribute('id').replace("name-", "https://www.someurlhere.com/page.html?id=") for i in 
browser.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[@id[starts-with(.,"name")]]')]
```

So I've basically replaced name- (start of line) with the url I wanted to append on the print. This way I can just do a browser.get(id) and it opens each url line by line.

Additional code as follows:

```
for id in ids:
    print(id,sep='')
    browser.get(id)
```